# download jdk 8 using puppet on windows 10

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I need to download jdk-8u45-windows-x64.exe on windows and install java. when i use pget it downloads a corrupt/unreadable file.

download.pp

```
class role::java {

pget{'Download java':
            source  => 'http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u45-b15/jdk-8u45-windows-x64.exe',
            target  => 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads',
        }
exec{"jdkinstaller":
  command => "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\jdk-8u45-windows-x64.exe /s ADDLOCAL=\"ToolsFeature,DemosFeature,SourceFeature\" ",
  creates => 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\javac.exe',
  logoutput => 'true',
 }

}
```

I tried using cyberious/windows_java from puppet forge but it didnt work either.
is there any other way to install java on windows.

Comment: When I try to open the link I get an error page to accept agreement. Chances are this is what gets downloaded during the pget and it is certainly not an executable . Please verify. I would advise you download it and host it somewhere where you directly get to your download

Answer (score 0):

Two issues in this manifest

1. The one [Exception_al](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7404435/exception-al) is mentioned.
2. as mentioned below in picture, you should escape "\". For this you have to use "/" instead of "\"
   [image]